# Using a class (User control) in stack

Tags: c#, int, private

I am sorry if this noob question. So we are learning user controls and this bit of code popped up.

```
private Stack<MyFirstUserControl1> _myControls = new Stack<MyFirstUserControl1>();
private int _controlsInstantiated = 0;
```

Can you use a class within a Stack? Can anyone explain? Noob question I'm sure...

Comment: Yes. In fact you have to use one (or a struct). :)

Answer (score 2):

`Stack<MyFirstUserControl1>` just means that the collection will be of `MyFirstControl1` type

Answer (score 1):

[Stack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw(v=vs.110).aspx) is nothing more than a LIFO queue so sure, its just a list/collection of objects that can be pushed and popped based on last-in-first-out and in this case its a list of instances of type `MyFirstUserControl1`.